# Can an Israeli citizen apply for Visa On Arrival in Thailand?

Tags: thailand

Can an Israeli citizen apply for Visa On Arrival in Thailand?

Or rather, due to being already eligible for 3 month **Tourist visa**, the option is closed for Israelis?

Comment: Why would you want a visa on arrival? AFAIK it has zero advantages over the regular visa exemption.

Answer (score 4):

Israel citizens are already visa exempted for Thailand.

Source - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visa_policy_of_Thailand#Visa_exemption_for_normal_passports